# Computing averages of records from multiple files with python

Tags: python, file-io

Dear all,
I am beginner in Python. I am looking for the best way to do the following in Python: let's assume I have three text files, each one with m rows and n columns of numbers, name file A, B, and C. For the following, the contents can be indexed as `A[i][j]`, or `B[k][l]` and so on. I need to compute the average of `A[0][0]`, `B[0][0]`, `C[0][0]`, and writes it to file D at `D[0][0]`. And the same for the remaining records. For instance, let's assume that :

```
A:  
1 2 3   
4 5 6  
B:  
0 1 3  
2 4 5  
C:  
2 5 6  
1 1 1
```

Therefore, file D should be

```
D:  
1     2.67   4    
2.33  3.33   4
```

My actual files are of course larger than the present ones, of the order of some Mb. I am unsure about the best solution, if reading all the file contents in  a nested structure indexed by filename, or trying to read, for each file, each line and computing the mean. After reading the manual, the `fileinput` module is not useful in this case because it does not read the lines "in parallel", as I need here, but it reads the lines "serially". Any guidance or advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: How big are your files? Can you read them all into memory, process them, and then write out the result?

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y From the question - *My actual files are of course larger than the present ones, of the order of some Mb.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [numpy](https://numpy.org/). It can read the three files into three arrays (using [fromfile](https://web.archive.org/web/20120708223516/http://www.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List_With_Doc#fromfile)), calculate the average and export it to a text file (using [tofile](https://web.archive.org/web/20120708223516/http://www.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List_With_Doc#tofile)).

```
import numpy as np


a = np.fromfile('A.csv', dtype=np.int)   
b = np.fromfile('B.csv', dtype=np.int)   
c = np.fromfile('C.csv', dtype=np.int)   

d = (a + b + c) / 3.0

d.tofile('D.csv')
```

Size of "some MB" should not be a problem.

Comment: thanks for your help! This is the power of python I want to exploit! I have just tried the np.fromfile function, but it does not read the numbers correctly. It seems that a better alternative is the function np.loadtext (my files are just txt files). Thanks again.

Comment: @user505047 - you're right, fromtxt is the right choice. I am glad you enjoy discovering numpy. It can save a lot off headache and time when manipulating large numeric arrays just like here.

Answer (score 0):

In case of text files, try this:

```
def readdat(data,sep=','):
    step1 = data.split('\n')
    step2 = []
    for index in step1:
        step2.append(float(index.split(sep)))
    return step2

def formatdat(data,sep=','):
    step1 = []
    for index in data:
        step1.append(sep.join(str(data)))
    return '\n'.join(step1)
```

and then use these functions to format the text into lists.

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference, here's how you'd do the same sort of thing without numpy (less elegant, but more flexible):

```
files = zip(open("A.dat"), open("B.dat"), open("C.dat"))
outfile = open("D.dat","w")
for rowgrp in files:     # e.g.("1 2 3\n", "0 1 3\n", "2 5 6\n")
    intsbyfile = [[int(a) for a in row.strip().split()] for row in rowgrp]
                         # [[1,2,3], [0,1,3], [2,5,6]]
    intgrps = zip(*intsbyfile) # [(1,0,2), (2,1,5), (3,3,6)]
    # use float() to ensure we get true division in Python 2.
    averages = [float(sum(intgrp))/len(intgrp) for intgrp in intgrps]
    outfile.write(" ".join(str(a) for a in averages) + "\n")
```

In Python 3, zip will only read the files as they are needed. In Python 2, if they're too big to load into memory, use itertools.izip instead.